# php json decode how to select and show one foreach items? not all?

Tags: php, json, foreach

```
foreach ($data as $result) { 
  echo '<div class="title"><a href="'.htmlspecialchars($result->link).'">'.htmlspecialchars($result->description).'</a></div>';
  if(!empty($result->attachment->media)){
    foreach ($result->attachment->media as $media) {
      echo '<div class="image"><a href="'.htmlspecialchars($media->{0}->href).'"><img src="'.htmlspecialchars($media->{0}->src).'" /></a></div>'; 
    }
  }
}
```

I have used this php json decode to get some data.
in the second foreach part `foreach ($result->attachment->media as $media)`, it returned 4 foreach items, but I just need the second one, how to select and show the foreach items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to show the second attachment, if it's an array , refer to it via it's index:

```
  $result->attachment->media[1]
```

Which would give you:

```
echo '<div class="image"><a href="'.htmlspecialchars($result->attachment->media[1]->{0}->href).'"><img src="'.htmlspecialchars($result->attachment->media[1]->{0}->src).'" /></a></div>';
```

Comment: Right, i am so fool, I add `media[1]`, but forget to remove the second foreach. thanks friend.